# Dual ouput switching power supply - NEGATIVE VOLTAGE?

Tags: operational-amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply

I am trying to power an opamp with a negative and positive voltage however I have a qeustion.. Can I take a negative voltage from this power supply?

[image]

I would take V1 and COM just as normal for my positive rail and take V2 and COM but switch them around for negative rail. Would this be possible?

Datasheet: https://docs.rs-online.com/c5e6/0900766b81621ffd.pdf

Website I want to buy from: https://benl.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/6447067/?cm_mmc=BE-PLA-DS3A-

Comment: No, both V1 and V2 are referenced to and positive w.r.t. COM.

Comment: You can use two separate such devices though. Then you can connect V+ from one to V- from the other and make this node the common voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The datasheet shows that there is only one COM for both supplies. Both supplies are positive with respect to COM.*

It's not suitable for your application.